# Display my form behind other windows

Tags: c#

I'm working with C# and I have a question.
How can I display my form behind other windows, my form will always display behind other windows.

Thanks

Comment: "my form will always display behind other windows." - then how will people get to it?

Comment: @MitchWheat http://images.wikia.com/elderscrolls/images/e/ea/Oh_stop_it_you.png `:)`

Comment: loop through all windows except your window and bring them to the front.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: My customer want to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<int, string> Windows = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public delegate bool WindowEnumCallback(int hwnd, int lparam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(WindowEnumCallback lpEnumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(int h);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetWindowText(int h, StringBuilder s, int nMaxCount);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EnumWindows(new WindowEnumCallback(AddWnd), 0);

        foreach (var item in Windows)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)item.Key);
        }
    }

    private bool AddWnd(int hwnd, int lparam)
    {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
            GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
            if (sb.Length > 0 && sb.ToString() != this.Name)
                Windows.Add(hwnd, sb.ToString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Nicolas Tyler, but it not "always" display behind :(